# Does this font match the logo symbol?

Tags: fonts, logo, critique

I'm trying to make a logo for a new company. 
My main symbol is this bubble with a target. Here is the symbol and how it looks right now.

Do you think the font matches the symbol?

[image]

---

[image]

> **Moderator’s notice:** The company behind the logo wants you to know that the above logos are outdated. However, please do not edit this question to change it, as the answers are based on these specific versions.

Answer (score 6):

*I'm uncertain what "matches" means.*

The symbol is really nice.

The type.. well it's just a font with some letter spacing in 2 faces. Not that in itself that's bad, but it doesn't seem to be as cohesive as the symbol.

- In the **stacked** version, the type is, in my opinion, *way too small* in comparison to the symbol.
- In the **horizontal** version, the leading seems much too large between the words.

Other than that, I would try and match the weight of the strokes in the boldface type with the outer circle of the symbol. It's fairly close in the horizontal version, but drastically different in the stacked version due to the smaller type.

Answer (score 4):

By match, I am assuming you are asking if the type and the symbol associate well.

I think picking a sans serif was the right way to go, it looks clean. I see a few problems with the type however:

**Kerning:** some of the spacing between letters is off (e.g. between C-A-M, P-A, I-G looks a bit wide)

**Alignment**: it looks off in both cases. For the stacked version, the symbol doesn't look centered visually and should appear more to the left. Also I agree with Scott when it comes to proportions; the type is too small. In the horizontal version, I think the line spacing should be decreased to make the group of type a bit tighter which will also help the alignement of your type with the circle. The curves of the symbol should end a wee bit further than the type to look visually aligned.

**Style**: As Scott also mentioned, the type is quite plain. I would personally try to play with adding some dimension like you do with the center of your symbol. The white notch could possibly be used in your lettering to make the whole thing more cohesive.

Apart from that, I think the bottom right part of the symbol needs a bit more work. It doesn't look quite symmetrical and you also want to avoid very pointy ends like this in a logo because they will not print nicely in small size.

Lots of information to take in but I think you're on a good track regardless :-)